# How can I reference a value from a static JS file in my node environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I hope you can help me.

I want to incorporate quill.js rich text editor into my node app.
This is how I've set up my files so far. I trimmed down the code to make the question easier to read.

Using an EJS template I reference the `scripts.js` file to initiate quill. `scripts.js` is a static file which is referenced through this method: `app.use(express.static('public'));`.

`index.ejs`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="container">

  <form action="/add/preview/<%= edmid %>/<%= delta %>" method="POST">

      <div id="editor">
      </div>
      <br>

    <input type="submit" value="ADD" class="btn btn-success"/>
  </form>


<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`scripts.js`

```
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');

var toolbarOptions = [
  [ {'color':[] },{'background':[]} ],
  [{'align':[]}]
];

var quill new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar:toolbarOptions
  },
  readOnly: false,
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

In order to get the contents of what is entered into the rich text editor you would normally use:
`var delta = quill.getContents();`

Ideally I would like to reference that `delta` value in my node environment. 
i.e:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:edmid/:delta', function(req,res) {

  var deltaVal = req.params.delta;

  res.render('pages/add-component', {
    title: "Add Item",
    deltaVal: deltaVal
  });

});
```

Please let me know if I have asked my question properly. 
I have tried to research this method I am thinking about but I honestly do not know what to search for into Google. I tried and failed miserably.

if any one could help me or show me where I could explore this idea further, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Moe

Comment: You need to send the value back to node.js using either a POST request (form submission) or ajax (XMLHttpRequest) or something similar (hidden iframe technique, jsonp etc.). You are already on the right path implementing an end-point in node to send the value to but I'd suggest not using query param or url path because the content of a text editor can be huge and exceed supported url length of the browser (different browser have different allowable length)

Comment: Thanks @slebetman. The only way I know how to get the value is to use `quill.getContents();`. I'll check out the documentation see if there is a different method that might integrate better.

Comment: @slebetman. I could find anything in the documentation. I'm considering the hidden iframe technique. Any other ideas are welcome.